# How do I automatically turn off my android tablet when battery is low

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, battery-life, power-options

I'm having problems with a android tablet that freezes when the battery runs low.
Is there an option in android or an app that could turn off the tablet when the battery is below a certain % of power left. Or that will turn the tablet off x minutes after last usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches possible. Some devices already ship with some kind of power management, which just needs to be enabled (check in *Settings*).

Apart from that, specific power management apps are available in the Playstore. E.g. [Battery Life Saver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Battery-Life-Saver/org.perfect.battery) can be configured to take actions on "battery low", like switching off WiFi, BT, and others (not sure if a power-off is included here as well). *Big Battery* promises to allow a shutdown at battery-low in [its donate version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/big-battery-donate/avs.android.bigbatteryDonate).

And then there's always [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) to do things like shutting down the device at 20%, or shutting off WiFi etc. at 30%, and so on. As a free alternative, [AutomateIt](http://www.appbrain.com/app/automateit-automate-your-droid/AutomateIt.mainPackage) can do the same. But I'm afraid in both cases, this will require a rooted device.

Comment: "You're afraid it requires a rooted device" <-- it's better if a device is rooted and it's free to do. So not something to feel sad about

Comment: @barlop sure thing to you and me (I start rooting my devices even before unboxing :) – but not everyone shares our feelings ;)